# Divison of int and double

Tags: java, int, double

```
int x=5, y=2;
System.out.println(x/y-(double)(x/y);
```

Why is the answer 0 when i run it on Eclipse?  I expect that (int)5/2 = 2 by property of shaving off the 0.5 left. Then (double)5/2 = 2.5, so 2 - 2.5= -0.5.

Answer (score 11):

The problem is that you've casted to `double` after the division:

```
(double)(x/y)
```

Integer division is still taking place, so the result is the same as `x/y`, and the subtraction yields `0`.

Cast `x` to `double` *before* the division, to force a floating-point division:

```
((double) x / y)
```

Answer (score 2):

Note you are missing a parenthesis to balance the expression. Assuming you correct it to this:

```
int x=5, y=2; System.out.println( x/y - (double)(x/y) );
```

The integer division of 5/2 is wrapped in parenthesis and therefore happens before the cast to double.

If you had this

```
int x=5, y=2; System.out.println( x/y - (double) x/y );
```

or this

```
int x=5, y=2; System.out.println( x/y - x/ (double) y );
```

you would get -0.5, because in each case the cast to double happens on the numerator or denominator before the division, which then as it doesn't happen between two ints, results in a double